# Cant bind .js file to main AngularJS file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, src

I have two simple files: `leads.html` and `leadsController.js`. I want to have `leadsController.js` as a linked javaScript file in `leads.html`. When I link it using the following code `<script src = "leadsController.js"></script>` in my `leads.html` ... `leads.html` does not render properly.

However, when I include the contents of `leadsController.js` as a part of the code of `leads.html` it works.

Am I not linking the .js file correctly?

Below is what works and what doesn't.

**I want this to work when connected to `leadsController.js`**

Yes ... it's in the same directory.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div ng-app = "myApp" ng-controller = "myCtrl">

      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat = "x in myData">{{ x.id }}</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <script src = "leadsController.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`leadsController.js` looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("https://clearmaze.net/test/newAdmin/leadsData.php").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data.records;
  });
});
```

**This works:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div ng-app = "myApp" ng-controller = "myCtrl">

      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat = "x in myData">{{ x.id }}</li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <script>

    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("leadsData.php").then(function (response) {
          $scope.myData = response.data.records;
      });
    });

    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should move `angular.min` before `leadsController.js`

Comment: @TanDuong thanks for the response ... `angular.min` is already before `leadsController.js`. Per your suggestion, I did try moving it around with no luck however.

Comment: How about `<script src = "./leadsController.js"></script>`

Comment: nope ... didn't work :'(

Answer (score 1):

try absolute uri of the script file. eg if ur script is in /scripts folder then
src="~/scripts/leadsController.js" that should work.

Comment: It's in the same directory under no additional folder ... so there's not much wiggle room there :( .. thanks though!

Comment: in browser use Inspect to find what is the src of js file. try ctrl+F5 to clear   of browser data.

Answer (score 0):

Try `<script src = "./leadsController.js"></script>`

Comment: please see console browser, right click on link `<script src = "./leadsController.js"></script>` open link new tab and check file exist.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: typo. I didn't upload the file to the server ... facepalm. Thanks all for your suggestions as they lead me to figure that out in the first place.